# Spring boot service higher response times under heavy load

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8

the response time of my spring boot rest service running on embedded tomcat sometimes goes really high. I have isolated the external dependencies and all of that is pretty quick.
I am at a point that I think that it is something to do with tomcat's default 200 thread pool size that it reserves only for incoming requests for the service.
What I believe is that all 200 threads under heavy load (100 requests per second) are held up and other requests are queued and lead to higher response time.

I was wondering if there is a definitive way to find out if the incoming requests are really getting queued? I have done an extensive research on tomcat documentation, spring boot embedded container documentation. Unfortunately I don't see anything relevant.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to check this